# Подскажите ветвь развития

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, архитектура

Здравствуйте!

Уровень знаний: junior php python, middle html/css/js (верстаю bootstrap+jquery). Из фреймов на php работал с fafreefraemwork. Писал по архитектуре MVC.

Ребят, вкратце так:
Готовлюсь к разработке сайта. Основная задача, запускать скрипты на питоне из личного кабинета.

Функционал личного кабинет:

- регистрация (все стандартно)
- оплата услуги(то есть наличие функции баланса и пикрутить модуль оплаты)
- личный кабинет, где собственно и запускается скрипт.

С запуском python скриптов из под php проблем нет.

Вот у меня делема, куда углубиться и на чем разработать этот личный кабинет. На php используя какой-то фреймворк или на django+python? Опыта и знаний по ООП мало.

Лично меня привлекает разрабатывать это все на php, по нескольким причинам: много тутироалов, широкое русское комьюнити, большое количество готовых реализаций чего либо. И т.к. это легче, выполню это быстрее.

Вот собственно все. В чем я ошибся? Что не учел? Спасибо.

Comment: Не бойтесь. Работа все равно сама направит вас в то или иное русло. РНР - это зло, но во благо. Много дыр, но лучшего, пожалуй, и не назову. Это просто инструмент. При грамотном использовании вполне хорош. Адд-оны выбирайте по-себе. Я, лично, их не приемлю

Comment: @DNS, просто у меня нет напарника или старшего товарища программиста, поэтому боюсь что с django просто увязну и все.

Comment: Зачем запускать Python из PHP? Почему бы не делать всё на Python? Берите Django да и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, собственно, не понял вопроса.

В ходе рассуждений, при его постановке, на мой взгляд, вы сами на него ответили.

Логично использовать те инструменты, которыми ты владеешь. А обучаться это, конечно, хорошо, но не на тех задачах, которые поставят под удар твой хлеб.

Если вам нравится php и вы в нём лучше соображаете, при этом не очень дружите с ООП и совсем не знаете django, то как по мне, используйте то, чем умеете пользоваться.

Если же вы хотите использовать django, то нужно изучить этот фреймворк. В сети есть много туториалов, документация на русском языке (правда для предыдущей версии, но различия там не большие). Но на мой взгляд для django, для серьёзных проектов не на костылях уровень junior вряд ли подойдёт.

Хотя я думаю, что stackoverflow никуда не денется и многое, с чем вы можете столкнуться, используя django, уже освещено, и нужно лишь правильно задать вопрос.

В любом случае, успехов вам